# Algorithm for moving between permutations by swapping with first integer

Tags: algorithm, sorting

I was asked an interesting interview question today. Suppose you have a permutation of the first n integers A (e.g. 13425) and another permutation B (e.g. 43125). We must move from the first permutation to the second, only by swapping values at indices 1 to n-1 with the value at index 0.

In other words, we can swap indices 0 and 1 in the sequence 13425 to yield 31425. But we cannot swap indices 2 and 3 in the sequence 13425 to yield 13245.

In the end, after these swaps we must come to permutation B. Can anyone come up with an algorithm with a better runtime than O(n^2)?

Answer (score 0):

yes, there is exists O(N) solution, here is java implementation:

```java
private static void swap(int[] idx, char[] c, int i) {
    idx[c[i]-'0'] = 0;
    idx[c[0]-'0'] = i;

    char tc = c[0];
    c[0] = c[i];
    c[i] = tc;
}

public static void permutation(final String from, final String to) {
    final int[] idx = new int[10];

    final char[] c1 = from.toCharArray();
    final char[] c2 = to.toCharArray();

    for (int i = 0; i < c1.length; i++) {
        idx[c1[i] - '0'] = i;
    }

    for (int i=(c1.length-1); i>=0; i--) {
        if (c2[i] != c1[i]) {
            final int charIdx = idx[c2[i]-'0'];
            if (charIdx != 0) {
                // move char to index 0
                swap(idx, c1, charIdx);
            }
            // move char from 0 to i;
            swap(idx, c1, i);
        }
    }
}
```